# Closed form of a sum with a falling factorial

Tags: summation, exponentiation, closed-form

I am having trouble finding the closed form for this:

$\sum_{k=1}^n  k^\underline{-2} + 2^k$

If it were just

$\sum_{k=1}^n 2^k + 2k$

I would just use the geometric series to solve for the closed form, but I do not know how to apply the geometric sum to the falling factorial. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Wait... back up... $k\frac{-2}{~}$?  How is there a negative number there?  That doesn't make sense.  I am only aware of allowing non-negative integers as the argument for a falling factorial.  Are you sure you don't mean $k\frac{2}{~}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the definition of [Falling Factorial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FallingFactorial.html), rewrite the sum as
$$\begin{align} \sum_{k=1}^n  k^\underline{-2} + 2^k &= \sum_{k=1}^n k(k-1) + 2^k \\&= \sum_{k=1}^n k^2-k + 2^k \\&= \sum_{k=1}^nk^2 - \sum_{k=1}^nk + \sum_{k=1}^n 2^k \end{align}$$ Then, use the known [formulas](https://brilliant.org/wiki/sum-of-n-n2-or-n3/).

Comment: $k(k-1)$ only. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks, I'd just seen the definition for the first time $(\ddot\smile)$

Comment: Your user name is just fantastic (when you see the symbol) !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you very much :) (a little usage of creativity)

Comment: Oh my, I feel so stupid now. It should have been obvious to just plug in the definition. Thank you.

Comment: @amk123abc Glad that it helps! I see that you are new to MSE. So, a small instruction  would be https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#:~:text=Accepting%20an%20answer%20is%20important,question%20read%20that%20answer%20first. Happy MSE :)

Comment: Just a quick follow up, the 2^k does not occur anymore after opening the falling factorial, right?

Comment: @amk123abc Why do you think so?